# Java Calculator - Find integers in string input

Tags: java, calculator

I am starting to create a calculator in java and I'm trying to loop through a string input and if there are any integers in the input, then add them to the ArrayList calcOperands. In the parseInput() method, I have done this for the operators using the charAt() method but I need something like intAt() to find integers in the string.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class stringCalculator 
{
private ArrayList<Integer> calcOperand = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Character> calcOperator = new ArrayList<Character>();
private String input1;

public stringCalculator(String input1)
{
    this.input1 = input1;
}

public void checkInput(String input1)
{
    boolean expression = input1.matches("[-+/*0-9]+[-+/*0-9]");
    System.out.println(expression);
}

public void parseInput()
{
    int s = 0;
    int e = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++)
    {
        if (input1.charAt(i) == '+' || input1.charAt(i) == '-' || input1.charAt(i) == '*' || input1.charAt(i) == '/')
        {
            calcOperator.add(input1.charAt(i));
        }
        //NEED TO FIND INTEGERS HERE
    }
}

public void printOperators()
{
    int n = calcOperator.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(calcOperator.get(i));
    }
}

public void printOperands()
{
    int n = calcOperand.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(calcOperand.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

This is my main method

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1 = scanner.nextLine();        
        stringCalculator c = new stringCalculator(input1);
        c.addOperators();
        c.checkInput(input1);
        c.parseInput();
        c.printOperands();
        c.printOperators();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Integer.parseInt()` on your `String`. That's the easiest way to get an `Integer` out of your input.

But be aware that it will throw an exception if it cannot parse it. So design your ui in a way the user is aware of the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would say to use string.split() here but you are in the odd situation of needing to find the transition between numbers and not numbers while keeping both sides of the transition. (i.e. 2+3 you can't throw away the +).

I would scan through the string, analyzing the current string till you identify it as either an operator or a number. Then put it into your array correctly. Once you identify it as a number `Integer.valueOf`, `Integer.parseInt`, `Double.valueOf`, and `Double.parseDouble` should help.

For a fully featured calculator (coping with BODMAS correctly) you can't rely on a simple Array, you need a tree structure too.

Answer (score 0):

Once you find an operator, split the string where the operator is at, remove the operator from the first part of the split string arrsy, then parse them to ints and store then in one big array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead having a `intAt()` method iterate your array list,Have a if condition to check whether the element is number or operator(already u have done).Then use `Integer.parseInt()` function to parse the Integer.